Why does my div with external image source download incorrectly
I am working on a project and I am so stuck. I need help.
Overview of the project: I am building a project that takes in a web address, goes to the web address, gets all of the images links in that address and returns it as an array. Each of the image links are now returned to the frontend in templates. Each template is simply a designed div with a space for an  tag when each of these image links go to. This is similar to what is obtainable at Pingenerator.com
The Problem: I can get all of these links and return them to the frontend but when I try to download the div using html2Canvas, I don't get to see the image.
Note that when i try to download the div using an image saved in my local drive, It downloads correctly. however when the image source is external it fails to download the image
This is my code
html2canvas($('#templated')[0], {
    useCORS: true, 
    allowTaint: false,
    logging: true,
    onclone: function(clonedDoc) {
        $(clonedDoc.getElementById('templated')).css('display', 'block');
    }
}).then(function(canvas) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.95);
    link.download = 'template.jpg'; 
    link.click(); 
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error occurred while rendering the canvas:', error);
});


Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP or CORS?

Thank you, Yes it is. I am building the app using Laravel. Also, I read somewhere that this issue could arise if the external image server does not support CORS.

Can you give us some examples of data that fails when you pass it into html2canvas()?

"Could arise" does not sound like you're actually having a problem?

Have you debugged this using your browser's developer tools, including the console and network tools? Any CORS or other errors should be apparent there.

yes, I get "access to image image link has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Ok. Well unless you control the server on which the image file is hosted, then you can't control that - the server needs to respond with that (and any other necessary CORS headers for the context) when your application makes the HTTP request for it. The only workaround would be for your canvas to make the HTTP request to a script on your own server (so that it's not cross-origin from the browser, meaning CORS won't apply), and then the server-side script would need to request the required image file itself (e.g. using cURL in PHP), and return the content to the browser, thus avoiding CORS.

When you have a canvas element and draw an image to it from an outside source, the canvas is 'tainted'. When a canvas is in this state, in most cases it will display as normal to the end-user, but you cannot read the pixel values from the canvas.
The reason for this is as follows:

Let's say your website is at example.com
In the browser, clientside, you load an image from example.net, a different site.
The image might be customized for the user, for example, the image might be dynamically generated and display as green for me & red if you were to load it.
You draw the image to your canvas
You try to read the canvas element.

At this time, if the read action wouldn't be prevented, a bad actor could deduce that the canvas is green. This is a security leak.
html2canvas has an FAQ that explains this as well.
You could proxy the images using a reverse proxy like nginx or you could download the images to your server first and serve them from the same origin as your website.
